# Overlay element at top-left corner of centered image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image which is currently centered on the screen using flexbox:

```
.center-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

<div class="center-flex">
    <img id="revealImage">
</div>
```

I am attempting to dynamically create a `div` that needs to be placed at the upper-left hand corner.  I have tried the following to get the computed `left` on the image but it does not work as it returns `auto` due to the flex layout.

```
const revealImage = document.getElementById('revealImage');

const left = window.getComputedStyle(revealImage,null).getPropertyValue('left');

let square = document.createElement('div');
square.style.height = '100px';
square.style.width = '100px';
square.style.zIndex = '2';
square.style.position = 'absolute';
square.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
square.style.top = 0;
square.style.left = left;

console.log('left: ' + left);
```

This results in a properly overlayed red box but it is centered and not set left.

[image: Showing rendered output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach in the html, by using the `picture` element in order to wrap the red square.

For example,

`html`:

```
<div class="center-flex">
    <picture>
        <img id="revealImage">
    </picture>
</div>
```

`css`:

```
picture {
    position: relative;
}
```

`js`:

```
const picture = document.querySelector('picture');

const square = document.createElement('div');

square.style.height = '100px';
square.style.width = '100px';
square.style.zIndex = '2';
square.style.position = 'absolute';
square.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
square.style.top = 0;
picture.appendChild(square)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kongallis/ju16rdfL/9/

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a small mistake(if I do not mistake):

Seem this is mistake:

```
square.style.left = left;
```

do:

```
square.style.left = 0;
```

is it right?

Comment: Unfortunately that will just put the element on the far left side of the screen.  The image is centered with flexbox.  0 is the edge of the screen, as least as I have the divs defined, which is probably where I'm going wrong.  I need the left edge of the image, not the screen.  https://i.imgur.com/KlmhMUG.jpg

Comment: @Patrick So you can set `position: relative` for div includes your red box, and set `position: absolute` and `left: 0` for the red box. right?